# System.Drawing.Imaging-like interface for Cocoa/iPhone image manipulation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, system.drawing.imaging

I'm looking for an image manipulation library for the iPhone/iPad, with similar functionality like System.Drawing.Imaging on the .net side.

Things I want to do:

- draw basic shapes, like elipses, rectangles, text
- draw it to a certain place on the screen, together with things like UILabels, UIViews, ... . Ideal would be the possibility to export to a data format which the UIImage control accepts (similar to the .net framework).

Does such a library exists in the standard frameworks, or do I need something else? Could you provide (a link to) some example code?

Thank you!

Yvan Janssens

Comment: yeah, I found that, but that's a game framework. I want to design stuff comparable to charts - simple graphical images to embed in the app. I think a game framework would be some kind of overkill ;-)

Comment: I'm currently taking a look @ ImageMagick. Will post if it'll work out ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything you need  with [Core Graphics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html)